# how to assign directory level user access in java spring boot web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot Web Application with multiple user roles and privileges. I found this [role and privilege for spring security](http://baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) article most close to what I want. It creates a dummy admin user when we first launch the application. Working fine without defining `hasrole` for URLs in AppConfig file.
Now when I define `hasrole` for URLs in AppConfig file it's not working well. Please help me configure it right. Here is my AppConfig class's `configure` method with httpSecurity

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() //public pages on this directory
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") //admin pages on this directory
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER") //user pages on this directory
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/dashboard", true)
            .failureUrl("/login?error=Invalid username or password!")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=You have logged out successfuly!")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

}
```

When I define `.antMatchers("/").permitAll()` without asterisk (**), the application throw 403 forbidden request error on the URLs defined for admin as well user URLs. If I put double asterisk (**) in the public URLs antmatcher like this `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`, the app do not enforce roles at all. And make all pages public
I may have multiple URLs as public URLs so, I want to define the role to allow all pages at the public directory to be accessible to everyone. The admin specific pages will have admin prefix i.e. `/admin/adminPagesURLs` and user-specific pages will have user prefix i.e.`/user/userPagesURLs`

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is hierarchic, you should define them from the most to the less specific mapping. In this case

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
.antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

However one might argue that this is bad practice as you might be unintentionally exposing more than you should. For example if you would add /secret/xyz in future and forget to specify the access control it would be accessible by everyone. Even spring encourages the use of a "deny-by-default" approach

> Always try to use a “deny-by-default” approach where you have a
>   catch-all wildcard (/** or **) defined last and denying access.

I would go for something like

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
.antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
.antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
.antMatcher("/**").denyAll()
```

Comment: I have tried the second approach in your answer. but app still throws 403 on admin and user urls

Comment: Are you logged in? How did you name your roles?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in. In database I have roles like ROLE_AMDIN and ROLE_USER